# onSelectionChange doesn't call a function

Tags: angular, autocomplete, nativescript

I have a question about my code.

I have this html code:

```
<StackLayout backgroundColor="#66cdaa" padding="5">
    <Label text="Select country"></Label>
    <RadAutoCompleteTextView [items]="dataItems" suggestMode="Suggest"
        displayMode="Tokens">
        <SuggestionView tkAutoCompleteSuggestionView>
            <ng-template tkSuggestionItemTemplate let-item="item">
                <StackLayout orientation="vertical" padding="10">
                    <Label (onSelectionChange)="updateForm($event, item.country_id, 'country_id')"
                        [text]="item.text"></Label>
                </StackLayout>
            </ng-template>
        </SuggestionView>
    </RadAutoCompleteTextView>
    <Label text=""></Label>
    <Button class="my-button" text="Sign Up" (tap)="register()"></Button>
</StackLayout>
```

I use this function `(onSelectionChange)="updateForm($event, item.country_id, 'country_id')"` for submit `country_id` in my form. This function doesn't call when I choose country.

In here is my [DEMO](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=Gbsjn1) project.

Comment: Why would you think `onSelectionChange` work? It's not an event exposed by `Label` component.

Comment: I use it in Angular project, I use it like :     `<mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayWith">
        <mat-option (onSelectionChange)="updateForm($event, country.country_id, 'country_id')" *ngFor="let country of filteredOptionsCountry | async"
          [value]="country.name">
          {{ country.name }}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-autocomplete>`

Comment: You can not compare two different components on different platforms, you might want to take a deep loop how events work in Angular. The component has to emit it in order for your listen to it.

Comment: Yes, but can you see demo please and suggest me how to solution a problem? Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">Country</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="sel1" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"
      [(ngModel)]="country.ID" (change)="updateForm($event)">
      <option *ngFor="let item of items" [value]="item.country_id">{{item.text}}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
```

Comment: Can you try it in demo project please? Thank you!

Comment: Thank you! In my Nativescript project I'm using this plugin https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-ui-samples-angular/blob/master/autocomplete/app/item/items.component.ts because I want something like this. Autocomplete, not drop down. If you can to see my demo and change it. Thanks again